# Android Configuration Changes and Asynchronous Tasks

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, interface

I know this is normal behavior for android but I'm running into the issue where my activity (which currently has my interface) is recreated when rotated. This causes problems with asynchronous tasks.

I am aware of the `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onSaveInstanceState` methods to keep my interface state intact.

Is it the best design practice for all of my interfaces to be contained in fragments instead of activities?

I understand I could create a fragment that has my list view and use the `setRetainInstance(true);` and keep the interface/async tasks attached upon rotation.

Is it a better practice to just use fragments as much as possible instead of activities.

My app communicates with a REST service. I believe I have an issue where if I start the request then rotate the screen I never get the response back.

Comment: why does "onConfigurationChanged" not work for you? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: "the issue where my activity ... is recreated when rotated." -- That's not an "issue," that's how Android is designed. Check the documentation.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you put all UI elements in fragments or activities. You need to properly handle your activity being recreated during orientation change. Use `onSaveInstanceState()` to save your state and re-load the state in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @323go I am aware of this.

Comment: @hfann I am already doing this.

Comment: I have updated my question and renamed the title to be easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, I personally do think using Fragments and retaining their instance state is a better practice as they don't get *completely* destroyed unlike Activities are - unless you want to handle the logic in a seperate class from the Activity that is created at first (`if(saveInstanceState == null) { this.connectionHandler = new MyConnectionHandler(); }`), and send using the Bundle and the `Parcelable` interface ( http://parcelabler.com ). I guess if you want to **hack** a bit, then instead of the activity, you should give the AsyncTask a class that holds the Activity reference and update that ref

Comment: although I will need to check if the instance reconstructed from the Bundle is the same as the previous one, although probably not, in which case the holder wouldn't work. You can also use the `LocalBroadcastManager` to send messages using `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have long running tasks, you should consider that the user may get interrupted while the task is in progress (e.g. they have to take a phone call or another urgent matter comes up the requires them to launch another app).

If a configuration change causes a problem for something that the user can't see, the problem is in how you handle that operation. If interrupting a long running task will cause problems for your app, then you should consider using a service or running the task in your application class (and in that order - using the `Application` class can cause other unwanted side effects).

Configuration changes and the resulting destruction and re-creation of an activity have to do with the issue "how do I design my app if the user changes their phone" should not be the cause of the problem you are having. Android is actually giving you an opportunity to consider how the change in the phone might impact the user *experience* - and modify the interface or interface elements accordingly.